# Нужно поменять местами первую и последнюю букву каждого слова в списке Python

Tags: python, список

Мы должны вводить текст с пропусками, в конце точка. На выводе получить слова, отличающиеся от последнего и в каждом слове заменить первую и последнюю букву местами.

Основная часть сделана, не могу понять, как сделать проверку каждого слова списка, сама идея что-то типо того:

```
a[-1] + a[1:-2] + a[0]
```

Сам основной код:

```
b = input("Введіть Ваш текст: ")
print(b)
removed = b.replace(".", "") 
a = list(removed.split())
new = [x[:-1] for x in a]
del new[-1]
#недостаящая часть
print
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

во первых если вы хотите отрезать точку именно в конце, то это надо делать так:

```
removed = b[:-1]
```

после того как вы разбили `removed` на список слов и знаете последнее - сформируйте новый список без последнего слова и одинаковых с ним:

```
new = [word for word in a if word != a[-1]]
```

т.е. в новый список входят все элементы старого не равные последнему элементу старого списка

ну а отрезать буквы можно просто

```
word[1:-1]
```

т.е. весь ваш код будет:

```
words = input("Введіть Ваш текст: ")[:-1].split()

text = ' '.join(word[1:-1] for word in words if word != words[-1]) + '.'

print(text)
```

это если вам надо на выходе строку собрать и вернуть точку (сужу просто по той же задаче, которая была вчера и позавчера на форуме :))

Comment: А если вот допустим, нужно, что бы просто в каждом слове последняя буква стала первой, а не просто удаляла последнюю и первую

Comment: И там просто нужна была проверка, схожие ли другие слова на первое, без удаления последнего

Comment: последняя стала первой - `text = text[-1] + text[1:]` или последняя должна встать на 1 место и исчезнуть из последнего - тогда `text = text[-1] + text[1:-1]`

Comment: на счет "просто проверки" - а что она давать - просто проверить? подсчитать кол-во одинаковых слов или что - если по проверке ничего не делается, то зачем вообще нужна проверка?